# How to properly install linux on Sony Vaio?

Tags: linux, installation, sony-vaio, system-reserved-partition

**TL;DR At Bottom.**

I'm planning on "blowing up" my Vaio once I graduate (uni) and switch to a Linux distro.

At first, I thought I be would OK with just overwritting the entire drive, but after some thought and analysis, I've come to notice that the drive comes with partitions that might need to stay there (e.g. OEM, EFI).

The drive is already on it's last leg (so to speak), but it's adequate for the distro I have in mind. Not to mention, space is not an issue (500GB).

Since this laptop is running with UEFI, I'm wondering if there's a recommended procedure for what I'm planning to do.

This laptop came with Windows 8 preinstalled, so I'm assuming that's the reason for the partitions it has now (along with all the upgrades I committed to).

Should I switch to legacy BIOS and install/write over the partitions I have (excluding the two mentioned)?

Or, can I keep UEFI enabled? The reason I'm thinking of going this route is because I may want to switch back to Windows at some point (doubtful). However, just in case, I figure I'd leave those two partitions there.

My laptop also comes with some extra functionality in that it allows for the user to be directed to a support menu of sorts via an ASSISST button on the laptop. Whether or not this is influenced by one of the partitions or dependent on having Windows installed is unknown to me.

Would that feature be lost when switching to Linux?

TL;DR:
I want to upgrade my Sony VAIO to Linux at some point. It came with Windows 8 preinstalled and I'm wondering if I need to do anything extra to maintain certain functions afterwards (e.g. ability to reinstall Windows at a later date & ability to use ASSIST function unique to Vaio).

How would one go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I'm not thinking of dual-booting. While I understand that I could most definitely install Windows again (without the partitions), I was under the impression that those partitions were there for a reason. What significance do they play in reinstalling Windows after the fact and do I even need them?

Comment: There are already so many tutorials about installing Linux for dual-booting with Windows with and without UEFI. You just need to look them up and do some reading.

Comment: @Larssend I don't want to dual boot. I want to make sure that once I install one OS, that I can still be able to install Windows again. Since my laptop came with Win8 installed, I can only assume that those partitions I mentioned shouldn't be touched. That is, if I want to use Windows on the machine again. I'm sure I could just as well install it again, but does those partitions have any other significance being there?

Answer (score 0):

All modern Linux distro can create automatically UEFI partitions or have wiki that explain how to create them.

My advice is to wipe all the partitions and install Linux on your clean drive.

In the (unlikey) evenience that you will turn back to Windows, wipe the full drive again and the Windows installer will take care of recreating all the partitions you need.

Comment: CAUTION! If you are going to wipe the entire drive, first you should make a backup of the factory restore partition and also make an image of your current Windows installation as a secondary backup.